# R言語とExcelのF検定

Tags: r, excel

ある2つのデータ群に対し、F検定をExcel、R言語それぞれで行いました。すると、ExcelはR言語の半分のP値になりました。

少し調べると、

1. Excelの分析ツールのF検定は片側検定
2. ExcelのF.TEST関数は両側検定
3. R言語のF検定は両側検定

であることが分かりました。

R言語の var.test() では, "two.sided" (両側), "less", "greater" を引数として選択できますが、片側検定 ("one.sided" ?) はありません。"less"、"greater" で片側検定になりますが、引数の順序で結果が変わります。

これを見る限り、F検定は通常、両側検定で用いられると判断して良いのかもしれません。しかしネット上で、「F検定は片側検定」と書かれているサイトを多く見つけました。

質問ですが、F検定は両側検定が基本なのでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己回答です、、
[Corss Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) で質問しました。

[In the F test, is a two-sided test mainly used?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407752/in-the-f-test-is-a-two-sided-test-mainly-used)
によると、

- 「小さい」を検定したいのなら"less"
- 「大きい」を検定したいのなら"greater"
- そうでなければ"two.sieded"

の3種類で、"one.sided" のような選択肢はあり得ないようです。
なお、t検定 (t.test() ) でも同様に "two.sided", "less", "greater" です。